# Restore Nuget always fails in Jenkins's workspace

Tags: .net, jenkins, nuget, restore

I have 3 projects under Jenkins: 1 project built fine, 2 projects met a problem with MSBuild from Jenkins: restoring Nuget packages always fails.

I copied the folder of the 2 projects from Jenkins's workspace into C:\, then open VS Community 2017 and build fine, but build in Jenkins's workspace by VS Community 2017 or by calling MSBuild from Jenkins still failed.

I changed the permission of Jenkins user to administrator, but same error.

Anyone can help me solve it out? Thanks so much.

The log of msbuild called by Jenkins:

```html
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\CRMwebApp.sln" (Rebuild;Clean;Build target) (1) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta-TRK-web-application\CRMwebApp.csproj" (Rebuild target) (2) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta.CRM.Services\Delta.CRM.Services.csproj" (default target) (3:3) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta.Barcode\Delta.Barcode.csproj" (default target) (4:3) ->
(ReportAssetsLogMessages target) -> 
  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.2\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(327,5): error : Assets file 'C:\Delta-TRK\Delta.Barcode\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta.Barcode\Delta.Barcode.csproj]


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\CRMwebApp.sln" (Rebuild;Clean;Build target) (1) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta-TRK-web-application\CRMwebApp.csproj" (Rebuild target) (2) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta.CRM.Services\Delta.CRM.Services.csproj" (default target) (3:3) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta.Barcode\Delta.Barcode.csproj" (default target) (4:3) ->
(RunResolvePackageDependencies target) -> 
  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.2\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(167,5): error : Assets file 'C:\Delta-TRK\Delta.Barcode\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta.Barcode\Delta.Barcode.csproj]


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\CRMwebApp.sln" (Rebuild;Clean;Build target) (1) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta-TRK-web-application\CRMwebApp.csproj" (Rebuild target) (2) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta.CRM.Services\Delta.CRM.Services.csproj" (default target) (3:3) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta.CRM.Core\Delta.CRM.Core.csproj" (default target) (5:13) ->
(ReportAssetsLogMessages target) -> 
  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.2\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(327,5): error : Assets file 'C:\Delta-TRK\Delta.CRM.Core\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta.CRM.Core\Delta.CRM.Core.csproj]


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\CRMwebApp.sln" (Rebuild;Clean;Build target) (1) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta-TRK-web-application\CRMwebApp.csproj" (Rebuild target) (2) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta.CRM.Services\Delta.CRM.Services.csproj" (default target) (3:3) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta.CRM.Core\Delta.CRM.Core.csproj" (default target) (5:13) ->
(RunResolvePackageDependencies target) -> 
  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.2\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(167,5): error : Assets file 'C:\Delta-TRK\Delta.CRM.Core\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta.CRM.Core\Delta.CRM.Core.csproj]


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\CRMwebApp.sln" (Rebuild;Clean;Build target) (1) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta-TRK-web-application\CRMwebApp.csproj" (Rebuild target) (2) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta.CRM.Services\Delta.CRM.Services.csproj" (default target) (3:3) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta.ErrorCodes\Delta.ErrorCodes.csproj" (default target) (9:3) ->
(ReportAssetsLogMessages target) -> 
  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.2\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(327,5): error : Assets file 'C:\Delta-TRK\Delta.ErrorCodes\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta.ErrorCodes\Delta.ErrorCodes.csproj]


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\CRMwebApp.sln" (Rebuild;Clean;Build target) (1) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta-TRK-web-application\CRMwebApp.csproj" (Rebuild target) (2) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta.CRM.Services\Delta.CRM.Services.csproj" (default target) (3:3) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta.ErrorCodes\Delta.ErrorCodes.csproj" (default target) (9:3) ->
(RunResolvePackageDependencies target) -> 
  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.2\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(167,5): error : Assets file 'C:\Delta-TRK\Delta.ErrorCodes\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Delta-TRK\Delta.ErrorCodes\Delta.ErrorCodes.csproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    6 Error(s)
```

Comment: Can you paste the error log at least?

Comment: I added it above. Build server: Windows Server2016 SP1, .NET Framework 4.6.2, JDK 9.0.1, JRE 9.0.1, git, Jenkins 2.73.3

Comment: Ok but this is error from msbuild, where is log from nuget restore? You wrote it fails.  I dont think msbuild does nuget restore by default. VS does but it a part of VS, not msbuild.

Comment: I am using msbuild of Jenkins same as msbuild of VS. Nuget restore failed, but not same log on VS vs. on Jenkins.

Comment: Nuget restore is not a part of msbuild. VS calls it before msbuild.

Comment: I updated NuGet Version 1.0.6 for solution and all sub-projects. Build successful right now.